# Application Missing Features after Deploying to Heroku ( Forem Gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, forem

When deploying my application to Heroku, I'm missing my user forum, as created by gem/engine Forem. I've had to do some db resetting both on locally and heroku, but locally I've found that running rails g install:forem restores the forem in my development environment. I've been unsuccessful replicating that success with heroku. I'm looking for either A) specific information about deploying with this gem, or B) general information about how to troubleshoot the issue. I'm happy to post code, but I'm sure sure what's relevant.

```
Gemfile:

gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'devise'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'pg'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'forem', github: "radar/forem", branch: "rails4"
gem 'forem-bootstrap', github: "radar/forem-bootstrap"
gem 'forem-theme-base', :github => 'radar/forem-theme-base'
gem 'forem-redcarpet', github: "radar/forem-redcarpet"
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.5'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Comment: Have you tried running `heroku run rails g install:forem` for your app?

Comment: I did and I got "Could not find generator install:forem."

Comment: Post your `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when deploying my Rails 4 application to Heroku.

I am using both Devise for authentication and Forem for generating the forums.
In my dev environment, I installed Devise and Forem based on this tutorial:

http://www.sitepoint.com/forem-rails-forum-engine/

When deploying, as all was already present in the dev environment (i.e. models), the only thing was to install Devise and Forem (with no need for other steps):

```
heroku run rails generate devise:install

heroku run rails generate forem:install
```

For each, I replied to overwrite files that could be present, but actually if you configured Devise or Forem, **keeping the files (initializers) you just uploaded would be a good idea !**

Et voilà !